# php - edit SESSION variable in multiple page form

Tags: php, session

currently I am doing multiple page form (page 1 and page 2). I save the details in page 1 using SESSION and insert successfully to database. I also successfully retrieve the data from database and display on page (activityLog.php).
However, I face problem when I want to edit/update the form.The value in the form  wasn't update as well as the database. Please help.Thanks.
Below is my display cause page and edit form (editIndividual.php).

**activityLog.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>My Activity Log</title>

<?php
    session_start();
    include 'header.php';

?>
<div id="content">

        <div class="section">
        <h4 align="center" style="font-size:28px;">My Activity Log</h4>
            <div>

                <a href="basic_setting.php">Basic Setting</a>
                <a href="change_password.php">Change Password</a>
                <a class="selected" href="activityLog.php">My Activity Log</a>
            </div>

            <label style="font-size:19px;color:#333;"<strong>Manage your cause below.</strong>

            <div class="figure">

                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" class="register">

                    <div class="first" >

                        <?php

                include 'dbconn.php';

                if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
                    $query="SELECT * from cause join user_info on cause.userID=user_info.userID where email='{$_SESSION['email']}'";
                    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                        $causeID = $row['causeID'];
                        $title = $row['title'];
                        $category = $row['category'];
                        $donateType = $row['donateType'];
                        $goal = $row['goal'];
                        $description = $row['description'];
                        $createDate = $row['createDate'];
                        $image = $row['image'];


                        echo "<a href='editIndividual.php?u=$causeID'>".$title."</a><br>";

                        echo "<img height='80' width='100' src='upload/".$image."'><br>";


                    }




                }

                ?>


                    <fieldset>

                </fieldset>

                </div>
                </form><!--end form-->

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php include 'footer.php';?> <!--include footer.php-->
</body>
</html>
```

**editIndividual.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />


    <!--include header-->
    <?php 
    session_start();
    include 'dbconn.php';
    include 'header.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){

        echo "Please login before proceed!";
        header("location:login.php");
    }


    else{

                    if(isset($_GET['u'])){
                        $causeID = $_GET['u'];


                    $query="SELECT * from cause where causeID=$causeID ";
                    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                        $causeID = $row['causeID'];
                        $title = $row['title'];
                        $category = $row['category'];
                        $donateType = $row['donateType'];
                        $goal = $row['goal'];
                        $description = $row['description'];
                        $createDate = $row['createDate'];
                        $image = $row['image'];

                    }


                    //update title
                    $title = $_SESSION['title'];
                    $upTitle = "UPDATE cause set title='$title' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upTitleResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upTitle);


                    //update category
                    $category = $_SESSION['category'];
                    $upCategory = "UPDATE cause set category='$category' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upCategoryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upCategory);

                    //update donate type
                    $donateType = $_SESSION['donateType'];
                    $upDonateType = "UPDATE cause set donateType='$donateType' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upDonateTypeResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upDonateType);

                    //update goal
                    $goal = $_SESSION['goal'];
                    $upGoal = "UPDATE cause set goal='$goal' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upGoalResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upGoal);

                    //update description
                    $description = $_POST['description'];
                    $upDes = "UPDATE cause set description='$description' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upDesResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upDes);

                    //update image
                    $image = $_FILES['imageToUpload']['name'];
                    $upImage = "UPDATE cause set image='$image' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upImageResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upImage);



                    }
    }

    ?>

                    <!--Change choose file button default name-->
                        <script>
                        function HandleBrowseClick()
                    {
                        var fileinput = document.getElementById("imageToUpload");
                        fileinput.click();
                    }

                    function Handlechange()
                    {
                        var fileinput = document.getElementById("imageToUpload");
                        fileinput.value;
                    }

                        </script>


    <div id="content">
        <div>
             <form action="activityLog.php" id="editInd_form" name="editInd_form" class= "register" method="post">
                <div class="first">
                    <fieldset>

                        <label for="title"><strong>Cause Title: </strong></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="inputtext" value="<?php echo $title?>"/><br>

                        <label for="category" ><strong><span class="error-message" style="color:red">*</span>Category:</strong></label><br>         
                        <select id="category" name="category" onchange="document.getElementById('editInd_form').submit()">
                            <?php
                            $categoryArray=array("Select a category", "Animal Welfare", "Children", "Education", "Environment", "Health", "OKU", "Refugees", "Senior Citizen", "Community", "Women Welfare", "Youth");
                        for ($i=0; $i<count($categoryArray); $i++){
                            if ($i == $category){
                                echo "<option value='".$i."' selected>".$categoryArray[$i]."</option>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$categoryArray[$i]."</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select><br>

                        <label for="donateType"><strong><span class="error-message" style="color:red;">*</span>Type of Donation:</strong></label><br>
                        <select id="donateType" name="donateType" onchange="document.getElementById('editInd_form').submit()"  >
                            <?php
                            $donateTypeArray=array("Please Select","Fundraising","Books","Clothing","Electric product", "Food","Water","Other");
                            for ($j=0; $j<count($donateTypeArray); $j++){
                            if ($j == $donateType){
                                echo "<option value='".$j."' selected>".$donateTypeArray[$j]."</option>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<option value='".$j."'>".$donateTypeArray[$j]."</option>";
                            }
                        }

                        ?>
                        </select><br>


                        <label for="goal"><strong><span class="error-message" style="color:red">*</span>Please state your goal:</strong></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="goal" name="goal" class="inputtext" value="<?php echo $goal?>" placeholder="enter an amount(RM) for fundraising, uniform, 1.5L mineral water, ..."><br>

                        </fieldset></div>
                            <div><fieldset>

                        <label for="description"><strong>Tell us your story: </strong></label><br>
                        <textarea name="description"  style="width:350px;height:150px;"><?php echo $description?>
                        </textarea><br>

                <!-- <img src="images/image-icon.png" class="image-icon" height="150" width="150"> <img src="images/video-icon.png" height="150" width="150">-->
                <label for="imageToUpload"><strong>Upload Your Photo:</strong></label><br>
                <input type="file" name="imageToUpload" id="imageToUpload" style="display:none;" onChange="Handlechange();"> 
                <input type="button" value="Change image" id="fakeBrowse" onclick="HandleBrowseClick();"/>
                        <?php include 'upload1.php';?>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="save" value=""><br>
            </fieldset>


            </div>







        </form>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div> <!--content end-->


    <!--include footer-->
<?php include 'footer.php';?> 
</body>
</html>
```

for your reference, this is my create form (2 pages form)
**createIndividual.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />


    <!--include header-->
    <?php 
    session_start();
    include 'dbconn.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){

        echo "Please login before proceed!";
        header("location:login.php");
    }
    include 'header.php';


    ?>


    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <h3 align="center"> Create your own cause</h3>
            <h4><strong> Step 1: Title, Category, Goal</strong></h4>
             <form action="createIndividual2.php" id="createInd_form" class= "register" method="post">
                <div class="form">
                    <fieldset>

                        <label for="title"><strong>Cause Title: </strong></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="inputtext"/><br>



                        <label for="category" ><strong><span class="error-message" style="color:red">*</span>Category:</strong></label><br>         
                        <select id="category" name="category">
                            <option value="0"> Select a category</option>
                            <option value="1"> Animal Welfare</option>
                            <option value="2"> Children</option>
                            <option value="3"> Education </option>
                            <option value="4"> Environment</option>
                            <option value="5"> Health</option>
                            <option value="6"> OKU</option>
                            <option value="7"> Refugees</option>
                            <option value="8"> Senior Citizen</option>
                            <option value="9"> Community</option>
                            <option value="10"> Women Welfare</option>
                            <option value="11"> Youth</option>
                        </select><br>

                        <label for="donateType"><strong><span class="error-message" style="color:red;">*</span>Type of Donation:</strong></label><br>
                        <select id="donateType" name="donateType">
                            <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                            <option value="1">Fundraising</option>
                            <option value="2">Books</option>
                            <option value="3">Clothing</option>
                            <option value="4">Electric product</option>
                            <option value="5">Food</option>
                            <option value="6">Water</option>
                            <option value="7">Other</option>

                        </select><br>

                        <label for="goal"><strong><span class="error-message" style="color:red">*</span>Please state your goal:</strong></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="goal" name="goal" class="inputtext" placeholder="enter an amount(RM) for fundraising, uniform, 1.5L mineral water, ..."><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="next" value=""><br>
            </fieldset>

            </div>







        </form>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div> <!--content end-->


    <!--include footer-->
<?php include 'footer.php';?> 
</body>
</html>
```

**createIndividual2.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />


    <!--include header-->
    <?php 

        session_start();

        $_SESSION['title'] = $_POST['title'];
        $_SESSION['category'] = $_POST['category'];
        $_SESSION['donateType'] = $_POST['donateType'];
        $_SESSION['goal'] = $_POST['goal'];
        include 'header.php';
    ?>

    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <h3 align="center"> Create your own cause</h3>
            <h4><strong> Step 2: Tell us your story</strong></h4>

            <form action="checkCause.php" id="createIndividual" class= "register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form">

            <fieldset>

                <label for="title"><strong>Tell us your story: </strong></label><br>
                        <textarea name="description" style="width:500px;height:150px;">
                        </textarea><br>

                <!-- <img src="images/image-icon.png" class="image-icon" height="150" width="150"> <img src="images/video-icon.png" height="150" width="150">-->
                <label for="imageToUpload"><strong>Upload Your Photo:</strong></label><br>
                <input type="file" name="imageToUpload" id="imageToUpload"> 
                <input type="submit" name="upload" id="submit" value=""><br>
                <button onclick="goBack()" id="back"></button>

                    <script>
                    function goBack() {
                        window.history.back();
                    }
                    </script>

                <?php include 'upload1.php';?>



            </fieldset>

            </div>




        </form>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div> <!--content end-->



<?php include 'footer.php';?> <!--include footer.php-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `editIndividual.php` you have a error. You first get data from MySQL and after that you setup data from sessions. But where you check if new data exist and return old if not exists?

Look my integration in your code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />


    <!--include header-->
    <?php 
    session_start();
    include 'dbconn.php';
    include 'header.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){

        echo "Please login before proceed!";
        header("location:login.php");
    }


    else{

                    if(isset($_GET['u'])){
                        $causeID = $_GET['u'];


                    $query="SELECT * from cause where causeID=$causeID ";
                    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                        $causeID = $row['causeID'];
                        $title = $row['title'];
                        $category = $row['category'];
                        $donateType = $row['donateType'];
                        $goal = $row['goal'];
                        $description = $row['description'];
                        $createDate = $row['createDate'];
                        $image = $row['image'];

                    }


                    //update title
                    $title = (isset($_SESSION['title'])&&!empty($_SESSION['title'])?$_SESSION['title']:$title);
                    $upTitle = "UPDATE cause set title='$title' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upTitleResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upTitle);


                    //update category
                    $category = (isset($_SESSION['category'])&&!empty($_SESSION['category'])?$_SESSION['category']:$category);
                    $upCategory = "UPDATE cause set category='$category' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upCategoryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upCategory);

                    //update donate type
                    $donateType = (isset($_SESSION['donateType'])&&!empty($_SESSION['donateType'])?$_SESSION['donateType']:$donateType);
                    $upDonateType = "UPDATE cause set donateType='$donateType' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upDonateTypeResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upDonateType);

                    //update goal
                    $goal = (isset($_SESSION['goal'])&&!empty($_SESSION['goal'])?$_SESSION['goal']:$goal);
                    $upGoal = "UPDATE cause set goal='$goal' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upGoalResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upGoal);

                    //update description
                    $description = (isset($_POST['description'])&&!empty($_POST['description'])?$_POST['description']:$description);
                    $upDes = "UPDATE cause set description='$description' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upDesResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upDes);

                    //update image
                    $image = (isset($_FILES['imageToUpload']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['imageToUpload']['name'])?$_FILES['imageToUpload']['name']:$image);
                    $upImage = "UPDATE cause set image='$image' where causeID='$causeID'";
                    $upImageResult = mysqli_query($conn,$upImage);



                    }
    }

    ?>

                    <!--Change choose file button default name-->
                        <script>
                        function HandleBrowseClick()
                    {
                        var fileinput = document.getElementById("imageToUpload");
                        fileinput.click();
                    }

                    function Handlechange()
                    {
                        var fileinput = document.getElementById("imageToUpload");
                        fileinput.value;
                    }

                        </script>


    <div id="content">
        <div>
             <form action="activityLog.php" id="editInd_form" name="editInd_form" class= "register" method="post">
                <div class="first">
                    <fieldset>

                        <label for="title"><strong>Cause Title: </strong></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="inputtext" value="<?php echo $title?>"/><br>

                        <label for="category" ><strong><span class="error-message" style="color:red">*</span>Category:</strong></label><br>         
                        <select id="category" name="category" onchange="document.getElementById('editInd_form').submit()">
                            <?php
                            $categoryArray=array("Select a category", "Animal Welfare", "Children", "Education", "Environment", "Health", "OKU", "Refugees", "Senior Citizen", "Community", "Women Welfare", "Youth");
                        for ($i=0; $i<count($categoryArray); $i++){
                            if ($i == $category){
                                echo "<option value='".$i."' selected>".$categoryArray[$i]."</option>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$categoryArray[$i]."</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select><br>

                        <label for="donateType"><strong><span class="error-message" style="color:red;">*</span>Type of Donation:</strong></label><br>
                        <select id="donateType" name="donateType" onchange="document.getElementById('editInd_form').submit()"  >
                            <?php
                            $donateTypeArray=array("Please Select","Fundraising","Books","Clothing","Electric product", "Food","Water","Other");
                            for ($j=0; $j<count($donateTypeArray); $j++){
                            if ($j == $donateType){
                                echo "<option value='".$j."' selected>".$donateTypeArray[$j]."</option>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<option value='".$j."'>".$donateTypeArray[$j]."</option>";
                            }
                        }

                        ?>
                        </select><br>


                        <label for="goal"><strong><span class="error-message" style="color:red">*</span>Please state your goal:</strong></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="goal" name="goal" class="inputtext" value="<?php echo $goal?>" placeholder="enter an amount(RM) for fundraising, uniform, 1.5L mineral water, ..."><br>

                        </fieldset></div>
                            <div><fieldset>

                        <label for="description"><strong>Tell us your story: </strong></label><br>
                        <textarea name="description"  style="width:350px;height:150px;"><?php echo $description?>
                        </textarea><br>

                <!-- <img src="images/image-icon.png" class="image-icon" height="150" width="150"> <img src="images/video-icon.png" height="150" width="150">-->
                <label for="imageToUpload"><strong>Upload Your Photo:</strong></label><br>
                <input type="file" name="imageToUpload" id="imageToUpload" style="display:none;" onChange="Handlechange();"> 
                <input type="button" value="Change image" id="fakeBrowse" onclick="HandleBrowseClick();"/>
                        <?php include 'upload1.php';?>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="save" value=""><br>
            </fieldset>


            </div>







        </form>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div> <!--content end-->


    <!--include footer-->
<?php include 'footer.php';?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi Ivijan, thanks for your reply. However, when i edit the field and click submit,  the value in both form and database are no updated. Please help..thanks